# Mongoose query which compares field values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say i have the following Scheme

```
TestSchema{
 val1:Number,
 val2:Number}
```

Would it be possible to write a query where all the results returned are where val1=val2 ?

If so , is there a way to use it when doing a populate ? (Perhaps inside the match field in the opts object ?)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the [$where operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). Using that you could at least return the elements where those fields match.

Example: db.myCollection.find( "this.val2 == this.val2" );

I'm not in a place to be able to test this right now, so you may have to play with it a bit, but that should get you started.

I also should mention, there is a significant performance hit when using $where operations, so use cautiously.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `$where` operator.

```
TestModel.find({
    $where: 'this.val1 <= this.val2'
}).
exec(function(err, results) {
    // results here
});
```

You can alternatively pass a function to `$where` to work with results.

As Chris has said, this is an expensive operation, so test how it works first before deploying to production.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `aggregate`:

```
Test.aggregate([
    // Add a field to each doc that indicates if the two fields match
    {$project: {
        val1: 1,
        val2: 2,
        isMatch: {$eq: ['$val1', '$val2']}
    }},
    // Filter to just those docs where they match
    {$match: {isMatch: true}},
    // Remove isMatch to get back the original doc
    {$project: {
        val1: 1,
        val2: 1
    }}
], callback);
```

You can't do this to compare fields in populated results, only the queried collection.

This should be faster than using `$where`.